# 'Please Select' placeholder text for select list in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using select lists within a form for jQuery Mobile. I want the default value to be 'please select' or some other placeholder text. At the moment im doing it with the following:

```
<label class="select">Age</label>
<select>
           <option value="">Please select</option>
           <option value="">18</option>
           <option value="">19</option>
           <option value="">20</option>
           <option value="">21</option>
           <option value="">22</option>
        </select>
```

However is there a standard way of doing this? For instance I dont want users to be able to submit the form with the 'please select' option selected. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can give it a try like this :

```
  <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >Select one...</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bringing the default one on top of the list is generally good practice. You should assign values to your option's elements. For instance the default one can be 0.

```
<option value="0">Please select</option>
```

And than on submit you can check if the value submitted is 0, return false; or something.

Comment: So the only way to stop a form being submitted with the helper text value is with javascript or server side validation? I wondered if there was a standard html5 or JQM method for doing this, it seems like quite a standard feature a lot of people would need.

Comment: Not necessarily server side. If you're validating your form using javascript you can prevent form submission using default selected value (0)

Answer (score 0):

In jQM it can be done like this:

```
<option value="" data-placeholder="true">Change Category</option>
```